# Scrapy Parser - Won't output Data

Tags: scrapy

I'm not sure why my results in scrapy shell work where as my script does not. I'd like to parse the listed columns and output the data to an external json file using the script.

I've tested in scrapy shell and received successful results. However, my script fails.

Scrappy shell test:

`scrapy shell https://wiki.dspt.info/index.php/Basic_Item_IDs_Page_1`

```
>>> response
<200 https://wiki.dspt.info/index.php/Basic_Item_IDs_Page_1>
>>> table = response.xpath('//*[@class="wikitable sortable zebra"]//tr')
>>> table.xpath('td//text()')[3].extract()
u' pile_of_chocobo_bedding '
```

Where as the script fails:

```
import scrapy

class BootstrapTableSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bootstrap_table"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://wiki.dspt.info/index.php/Basic_Item_IDs_Page_1',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//*[@class="wikitable sortable zebra"]//tr'):
            yield {
                'id' : row.xpath('td//text()')[0].extract(),
                'name': row.xpath('td//text()')[3].extract(),
                'stackable': row.xpath('td//text()')[5].extract(),
                'category': row.xpath('td//text()')[9].extract(),
                'vendor_price': row.xpath('td//text()')[11].extract()    

            }
```

Data is parsed and exported to a json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fails on the first row of table with headers. This `tr` contains only `th` and no `td`, that's why the error is `IndexError: list index out of range`. To avoid it just skip row with empty data, like here:

```
import scrapy


class BootstrapTableSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bootstrap_table"
    start_urls = ['https://wiki.dspt.info/index.php/Basic_Item_IDs_Page_1'] 

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//*[@class="wikitable sortable zebra"]//tr'):
            data = row.xpath('td//text()').extract()
            if not data:  # pay attention how we skip empty row here
                continue
            yield {
                'id': data[0],
                'name': data[3],
                'stackable': data[5],
                'category': data[9],
                'vendor_price': data[11]
            }
```

Output:

```
...
2019-04-30 08:48:50 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-04-30 08:48:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://wiki.dspt.info/index.php/Basic_Item_IDs_Page_1> (referer: None) ['cached']
2019-04-30 08:48:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://wiki.dspt.info/index.php/Basic_Item_IDs_Page_1>
{'category': u' #N/A ', 'stackable': u' 1 ', 'vendor_price': u' 198\n', 'id': u' 1 ', 'name': u' pile_of_chocobo_bedding '}
2019-04-30 08:48:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://wiki.dspt.info/index.php/Basic_Item_IDs_Page_1>
{'category': u' Furnishings ', 'stackable': u' 1 ', 'vendor_price': u' 391\n', 'id': u' 2 ', 'name': u' simple_bed '}
2019-04-30 08:48:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://wiki.dspt.info/index.php/Basic_Item_IDs_Page_1>
{'category': u' Furnishings ', 'stackable': u' 1 ', 'vendor_price': u' 1403\n', 'id': u' 3 ', 'name': u' oak_bed '}
2019-04-30 08:48:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://wiki.dspt.info/index.php/Basic_Item_IDs_Page_1>
{'category': u' Furnishings ', 'stackable': u' 1 ', 'vendor_price': u' 10100\n', 'id': u' 4 ', 'name': u' mahogany_bed '}
2019-04-30 08:48:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://wiki.dspt.info/index.php/Basic_Item_IDs_Page_1>
{'category': u' Furnishings ', 'stackable': u' 1 ', 'vendor_price': u' 1564\n', 'id': u' 5 ', 'name': u' bronze_bed '}
2019-04-30 08:48:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://wiki.dspt.info/index.php/Basic_Item_IDs_Page_1>
{'category': u' Furnishings ', 'stackable': u' 1 ', 'vendor_price': u' 12406\n', 'id': u' 6 ', 'name': u' nobles_bed '}
2019-04-30 08:48:51 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://wiki.dspt.info/index.php/Basic_Item_IDs_Page_1>
{'category': u' #N/A ', 'stackable': u' 1 ', 'vendor_price': u' 0\n', 'id': u' 7 ', 'name': u' gold_bed '}
...
```

Comment: I see. I've also tried pointing it to tbody where content is stored, i.e. ```for row in response.xpath('//*[@class="wikitable sortable zebra"]//tbody/tr'):``` but it still fails. The code you posted is not working either so i'm a little stumped.

Comment: You should not use `tbody` in your code, it does not exist in reality, `tbody` is tag automatically added by browsers like Firefox and Chrome. Here is the explanation: https://hexfox.com/p/having-trouble-extracting-the-tbody-element-during-my-web-scrape/

Comment: I've added full spider code and trace that this code works.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful to know!